# Ant to Gradle conversion: Obfuscation and Jar

Tags: java, gradle, ant, jar, build.gradle

I'm performing a migration of ant to gradle. I'm stuck on something rather fundamental, I think. I have an .xml script that performs the following actions:

```
<target name="ANTtarget">
   <proguard
     ...
     <libraryjar dir="otherfiles/here" />
     <outjar name="some.jar"/>
     ...
   </proguard>

   <jar destfile="some.jar" update="yes" >
       <manifest>
         <attribute  name="Main-Class" value="some.package.here" />
       </manifest>
       <zipgroupfileset dir="otherfiles/here" includes="**/*.jar" />
   </jar>
 </target>
```

So, using proguard, the classes get obfuscated and then packaged. I'm able to complete an identical obfuscation, but I'm unable to complete the jar-ing. I suspect that it's due to there being no 'update="yes"' feature in gradle's jar task.

Gradle code:

```
task GRADLEtask(type: proguard.gradle.ProGuardTask) {
   ...
   outjar: "some.jar"
   ...
}
```

Is there any solution or workaround to the update jar? Maybe edit the manifest while I'm in proguard? (The idea here is that the task/target outputs are identical.)

**EDIT:**

**Normal jar-type task works fine; was incorrectly referencing the "otherfiles/here" in the jar task.**

CODE FOR REFERENCE:

[you probably won't have the same problem 'cuz you smart.]

```
task JARitUP (type: Jar, dependsOn: 'GRADLEtask') {
    baseName = "some2"

    from zipTree('some.jar')
    //get all the library jars
    def MYjars =  fileTree(jarPlace).filter { it.name.endsWith('.jar') }.files.path
    MYjars.each { THISjar -> from zipTree("$THISjar") }

    manifest {
        attributes 'Main-Class': 'some.package.here'
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's only a guess but could be that you're invoking directly your `GRADLEtask` which obfuscate the code?

Try using `dependsOn` to be sure that `jar` task invokes your obfuscation task previously, something like this in your **build.gradle**

```
jar.dependsOn(obfuscate)
```

And then invoke `gradle jar`

Comment: It was actually me incorrectly referencing the local jar library "otherfiles/here." Did it correctly in GRADLEtask, messed it up in the jar-ing task. No clue how I managed that.

Thanks, though.

Comment: Admittedly, it kind of blows my mind that an obfuscated jar can be used to generate another jar. Isn't the whole point of obfuscation that no one but the dev knows what it is?

Answer (score 2):

Something like:

```
apply plugin: 'java'

configurations {
   proguard
}

dependencies {
   "com.foo:proguard:1.2.3"
}

jar {
   manifest {
      attributes('Main-Class': 'some.package.here')
   }
}

task proguard {
   inputs.file jar.archivePath
   outputs.file jar.archivePath // is this correct?
   doLast {
      ant.taskdef(name: 'proguard', classname: 'foo.bar.ProguardTask', classpath: configurations.proguard.asPath)
      ant.proguard {
         libraryjar(dir: 'otherfiles/here') // not sure what this does
         outjar(name: jar.archivePath)
      }
   }
}
assemble.dependsOn proguard
proguard.dependsOn jar
```

Comment: Using the ant tasks would have worked, but I wanted to avoid them. No clear reason why. Probably because it would make the conversion easier, and we can't have that.

Comment: Thankfully, it seems that the proguard gradle task is maintained by proguard so I'd probably use this too. I often find that the ant task is usually maintained in-house but the gradle task is maintained by a 3rd party. In these instances I'll often favour the ant task over a 3rd party gradle plugin